# Do I need to worry about Valgrind reporting errors outside the scope of my application?

Tags: c, linux, valgrind, libc

When running Valgrind's `memcheck` tool, I often get many hundreds of thousands (or more, since Valgrind cuts off at 100K) of small invalid read statements, e.g.:

```
==32027== Invalid read of size 1
==32027==    at 0x3AB426E26A: _IO_default_xsputn (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
==32027==    by 0x3AB426CF70: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
==32027==    by 0x3AB42621FA: fwrite (in /lib64/libc-2.5.so)
==32027==    by 0x4018CA: STARCH_gzip_deflate (in /home/areynolds/trunk/utility/applications/bed/starch/bin/starch)
==32027==    by 0x401F48: compressFileWithGzip (in /home/areynolds/trunk/utility/applications/bed/starch/bin/starch)
==32027==    by 0x4028B5: transformInput (in /home/areynolds/trunk/utility/applications/bed/starch/bin/starch)
==32027==    by 0x402F12: main (in /home/areynolds/trunk/utility/applications/bed/starch/bin/starch)
==32027==  Address 0x7febb9b3c is on thread 1's stack
```

These statements refer to calls to functions outside of my application ("`starch`") and which appear to be part of `libc`. Is this something I need to be concerned with?

**EDIT**

If I modify the `fwrite` call to remove one byte, then my gzip stream gets corrupted. Here's the original code:

```
int STARCH_gzip_deflate(FILE *source, FILE *dest, int level) {                                                                                                                                                                                                              

    int ret, flush;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    unsigned have;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    z_stream strm;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    unsigned char in[STARCH_Z_CHUNK];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    unsigned char out[STARCH_Z_CHUNK];                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

    /* initialize deflate state */                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    strm.zfree = Z_NULL;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    /* deflateInit2 allows creation of archive with gzip header, i.e. a gzip file */                                                                                                                                                                                        
    /* cf. http://www.zlib.net/manual.html */                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    ret = deflateInit2(&strm, level, Z_DEFLATED, (15+16), 8, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);                                                                                                                                                                                           
    if (ret != Z_OK)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
        return ret;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

    /* compress until end of file */                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    do {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        strm.avail_in = fread(in, 1, STARCH_Z_CHUNK, source);                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        if (ferror(source)) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            (void)deflateEnd(&strm);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
            return Z_ERRNO;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
        flush = feof(source) ? Z_FINISH : Z_NO_FLUSH;                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
        strm.next_in = in;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

        do {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            strm.avail_out = STARCH_Z_CHUNK;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
            strm.next_out = out;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            ret = deflate(&strm, flush);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            assert(ret != Z_STREAM_ERROR);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
            have = STARCH_Z_CHUNK - strm.avail_out;     

            /* invalid read happens here */                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
            if (fwrite(out, 1, have, dest) != have || ferror(dest)) {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                (void)deflateEnd(&strm);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                return Z_ERRNO;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
            }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        } while (strm.avail_out == 0);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        assert(strm.avail_in == 0);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         

    } while (flush != Z_FINISH);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    assert(ret == Z_STREAM_END);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

    /* clean up and return */                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    (void)deflateEnd(&strm);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    return Z_OK;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I think I see the problem. I have `in[STARCH_Z_CHUNK]` and not `in[STARCH_Z_CHUNK + 1]` (and likewise for `out[]`). If I adjust both of the `fread` and `fwrite` statements by `-1`, I don't seem to get those `Invalid read of size 1` statements, although I still see a lot of `Invalid read of size 4` and `8` which are specific to `zlib`:

```
==32624== Invalid read of size 4
==32624==    at 0x3AB5206455: deflateInit2_ (in /usr/lib64/libz.so.1.2.3)
==32624==    by 0x40180E: STARCH_gzip_deflate (in /home/areynolds/trunk/utility/applications/bed/starch/bin/starch)
==32624==    by 0x401F48: compressFileWithGzip (in /home/areynolds/trunk/utility/applications/bed/starch/bin/starch)
==32624==    by 0x402C03: transformInput (in /home/areynolds/trunk/utility/applications/bed/starch/bin/starch)
==32624==    by 0x402F12: main (in /home/areynolds/trunk/utility/applications/bed/starch/bin/starch)
==32624==  Address 0x7feafde38 is on thread 1's stack
```

**EDIT 3**

I am recompiling with `-g` which, as mentioned, does associate line numbers with errors.

But I'm just doing a straightforward `strncpy` of `argv[]` variables, e.g.:

```
strncpy(uniqTag, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
```

This should copy over the null-terminated `argv[2]` string to `uniqTag`, but `valgrind` still marks this as an error.

**EDIT 4**

Here's the error message:

```
==3682== Invalid read of size 1
==3682==    at 0x4A081C1: strncpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:329)
==3682==    by 0x4022F1: parseCommandLineInputs (starch.c:589)
==3682==    by 0x402F20: main (starch.c:46)
==3682==  Address 0x7fedffe11 is on thread 1's stac
```

Here are the two relevant lines; valgrind is saying the second line is an invalid read:

```
uniqTag = (char *)malloc(strlen(argv[2]) + 1); 
strncpy(uniqTag, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
```

Because `strlen(argv[2]) + 1 > strlen(argv[2])`, this should result in a null-terminated `uniqTag`.

Comment: Actually it's probably your buffer that needs to get a bit larger, rather than fwrite() that needs to restrain itself...

Comment: Try increasing the size of the buffers by 1 at first and see what happens

Comment: BTW, are you compiling your code with debugging symbols ? If you use -g in the compiler options (assuming you use gcc) valgrind will give out more precise and useful messages.

Comment: what is the valgrind error wrt the strncpy() call ?

Comment: you do have a second argument to your program, right ?

Comment: Note that valgrind warns you about an invalid _read_. That means it thinks that something is wrong with the argv[2] part of the function call, rather than the uniqTag part.

Comment: Same conclusion can be extracted by the reference to the process stack, rather than its heap...

Comment: Although if there was no second argument, the program would probably crash at the strlen part... Hmm... strange... Do you do anything involving argv between those two lines ? what is your OS and valgrind version ?

Comment: If you use printf("%p") to print the value of the argv[2] pointer you might get a better idea on what is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case I'd say that you do. The libc function arguments come from your program. I'd hazard a guess and say that you have an off by one error in your code that leads fwrite to read one byte past the end of its source buffer.

EDIT:

By the way, such a small error can often remain unseen (i.e. your code does not crash) because both the compiler and the memory allocator usually allocate memory blocks in specific sizes and align them at word edges. This means that many times there is a small region past the requested buffer end that you can access without triggering the memory protection code. Of course your code might just break if you change compiler, libc, platform or bitness (e.g. go from 64 to 32 bit).

Valgrind has suppression lists for expected errors in libc, which you can usually find at /usr/lib64/valgrind/default.supp or /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp. There are quite a few issues that valgrind detects in libc, many of them intentional in an effort to optimise the code, but due to the suppresions in 99% of the cases it's the tested code that causes the problem.

EDIT2:

Keep in mind that, like most debugging tools, Valgrind will output infinitely more useful information on the issues it detects if you compile your code with debugging symbols. It will be able to point you to specific lines of code that are related to the issue - even if quite often they are not where the actual issue lies. If you use GCC just add -g to its options to compile your code with debugging symbols. In a production release, though, please remember to remove that flag!

Comment: +1 for _off_  _by_  _one_ suggestion.  I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow down the call stack until you get to some code that is yours and look for the error's origin.  In this case, `STARCH_gzip_deflate` appears to be calling `fwrite`  with something that is bad (probably a bad `FILE *` or the buffer you are attempting to write out) which is causing the valgrind to bark at you.

It is possible that this is not actually an error or that it is not your error, though.  But it probably is.